# Creating custom form that requires authentication when opening new project in QGIS?

Tags: authentication

I have a project in Qgis, and the layers I have stored in a Postgis database, I have created the credentials from the authentication menu and I have chosen the basic authentication method, I have only put user but not password to make it easier , but I do not accept the user (the credentials), you know what can be?

---

I introduce the data for a basic authentication, (user and password), of the PostGis connection. Then I save the changes and close the project. I reopen the project and then when I try to open the connection it asks me the master password and it gives me error and I get this message.[image]

Comment: could you maybe provide a screenshot(with backout username for safety reasons) and a potential error message?